# Grails where query criteria qualification

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to qualify method parameters versus domain properties in a Grails *where* query criteria when they are named identically?

For example:

```
def getPeople(age, sex) {
    People.find { age == age && sex == sex }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this!?

```
def getPeople(age, sex) {
    People.find { delegate.age == age && delegate.sex == sex }
}
```